# Are there any differences between a "newly defined" path and a path using predefined nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am not sure how I should phrase my question.

consider the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0] at (0,0) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (3,0) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (3,3) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (0,3) (d) {};

\draw[fill=black!10] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!30] (b) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (c) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only the second \draw command gets filled. In the first case not even the cycle operation works.

As far as I checked, when you use consecutive (predefined) nodes in a path (e.g. `(a) -- (b)`) then the filling operation doesn't work correctly. If you define new coordinates in the path (e.g. `(6,0) -- (6,3)`) then there are no problems.

Is this behavior normal?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because when you specify just the node name, without an anchor, the *border* of the node is used to draw the line. Even with `inner sep=0pt`, this point will be different depending on the direction of the line to be drawn. In order to achieve the desired result, you should explicitly use an anchor (like `center`), or define `coordinate` nodes instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0] at (0,0) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (3,0) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (3,3) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0] at (0,3) (d) {};
\coordinate (A) at (7,0);
\coordinate (B) at (10,0);
\coordinate (C) at (10,3);
\coordinate (D) at (7,3);

\draw[fill=black!10] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!10] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!30] (b.center) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (c.center) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I was just typing the same answer ;-) The border is also dependent on `outer sep` which is `.5\pgflinewidth` by default. But even when this one is set to zero the `fill` operation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Jake's answer, I found the relevant section in the tikz manual (v 2.10 section 16.2.1 "Predefined Shapes")

An alternative syntax, would be to use the node shape `coordinate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[coordinate] at (0,0) (a) {};
\node[coordinate] at (3,0) (b) {};
\node[coordinate] at (3,3) (c) {};
\node[coordinate] at (0,3) (d) {};

\draw[fill=black!10] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!30] (b) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (c) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\coordinate` is shorthand for `\node[coordinate]`; so the two expressions are equivalent, but in my opinion using `\coordinate` is clearer, because you don't need the empty pair of brackets (a `coordinate` node can't have a label text anyway).

Comment: @Jake, yeah i know I just posted for reference, in case somebody wants to check the manual.