# **Why** does cycle not return to the starting node **at all** if I construct a path between predefined nodes, rather than coordinates, in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

`cycle` doesn't work as I would naïvely expect it to if I use the `node` operation rather than `coordinate` to mark my points. I realise that, in the case of a node, TikZ is drawing to and from the borders of the nodes. So I can understand that the triangle is not filled because TikZ might regard the path as a non-closed one. (Although in other cases, it will actually finish a path in order to fill it as requested.) But why is the final size of the triangle not even drawn?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={draw}]
  \node (a)  at (-1,1) {};
  \node (c)  at (-1,-1) {};
  \node (f)  at (1,1) {};
  \filldraw (a) -- (c) -- (f) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[pmav99 asked this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18799/are-there-any-differences-between-a-newly-defined-path-and-a-path-using-predef) in 2011. However, the answers there do not obviously explain to me why nothing is drawn at all. I could understand if the final line returned to the border anchor of `(a)` from which the path began. I could also understand if it returned to the border anchor of `(a)` which it would use if I wrote `-- (a)` rather than `-- cycle`. But why does it not appear to go anywhere? (Or where does it go, if it goes somewhere, and why?)

I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but I can't find an explanation of this specific aspect of what TikZ is doing.

Also, I of course know that `\coordinate (a) ...` etc. would make more sense here, that I could define the points while constructing the path etc. I know how to avoid the problem. What I want to understand is the precise whys of why that problem occurs in the particular form it does. What exactly is `-- cycle` doing in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because each of them are separate paths from each node shape border to the other.

The final construction is equivalent to (using convenience of their locations)

```
\filldraw (a.-90) -- (c.90) % pen is lifted here hence a new path starts
          (c.45) -- (f.-135) -- cycle;
```

Hence `cycle` goes back to `(c.45)` as it is the starting point of the unbroken path redrawing the last portion of the path creating a zero area.

Put anything that is not collinear between (c) and (f) and you get a fill

```
\filldraw (a) -- (c) -- (1,-1) --(f) -- cycle;
```

[image]

Coordinates on the other hand have no border shapes but only a center anchor hence they constitute as valid path points thus cycle goes back to `a` since that is the first point of the continuous path.

Comment: Nitpick: But it *is* one whole path, not separate ones. But yes, a move to operation happens. And the PGFmanual says: “This causes the straight line from the current point to go to the last point specified by a move-to operation.”

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes probably I should have said *pen down* instead unbroken since it is a PDF operation.