# \filldraw is not filling

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, fill

I have an image in my thesis where I am discussing the similarities of basic colour concepts and a compass. The original image is something I shabbily shoved together in Paint, but I thought I could make it a little better by shabbily shoving something together with `tikz`. This is the original image:
[image: the colour spectrum as a compass]
My plan is to have in the end something vaguely resembling this, but at the moment I am stuck because the area I'm trying to fill with black won't fill and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is how it looks at the moment:
[image: progress on the compass]

I wanted the area between the two north lines to be coloured black. And this is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,]

    % circles (from centre)
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=1cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (centre) at (0,0) {};
        
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=4.5cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (inedge) at (0,0) {};
        
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=5cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (outedge) at (0,0) {};
    
    % main direction nodes
    \begin{scope}[label distance=0.5cm]
    % North
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=above:\Large{$\mathcal{N}$}] (N) at (0,3.5) {};
        
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (n) at (0,3.5) {};
    % East  
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=right:\Large{$\mathcal{E}$}] (E) at (3.5,0) {};
        
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (e) at (3.5,0) {};
    % South
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=below:\Large{$\mathcal{S}$}] (S) at (0,-3.5) {};
        
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (s) at (0,-3.5) {};
    % West  
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=left:\Large{$\mathcal{W}$}] (W) at (-3.5,0) {};
        
        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (w) at (-3.5,0) {};
    \end{scope}
    
    % mainlines
    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (N);
        
    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (E);

    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (S);

    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (W);

    % Main points
    \filldraw[black] (-0.35cm,0.35cm) -- (N) -- (centre) -- cycle; % why u no fill?!!

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I do realise that my code is very repetitive but I have both tried to define the aspects of the `tikzpicture` and creating a `/.style` but had no success so I decided to do it this way so that it works and clean it up later when I've all the details figured out.

Comment: Aside: If you always use the same set of keys for something you can do `\begin{tikzpicture}[myline/.style = {thick,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}}]` then do `\draw[myline] (centre) -- (N);`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, I do realise this. Most of my attempts to do so however have failed to produce anything except errors. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I suspect that your contribution will help a lot! Thank you :)

Comment: That is just to make the code shorter by avoiding duplication.  The solution to your problem here is what Ulrike said: replace the node `centre` by the coordinate `centre.center`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes. I have accepted her answer, but you have also helped very much and you didn't have to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use coordinates instead of nodes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,]

    % circles (from centre)
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=1cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (centre) at (0,0) {};

    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=4.5cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (inedge) at (0,0) {};

    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=5cm,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=1.5pt,amplitude=0.2pt}] (outedge) at (0,0) {};

    % main direction nodes
    \begin{scope}[label distance=0.5cm]
    % North
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=above:\Large{$\mathcal{N}$}] (N) at (0,3.5) {};

        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (n) at (0,3.5) {};
    % East
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=right:\Large{$\mathcal{E}$}] (E) at (3.5,0) {};

        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (e) at (3.5,0) {};
    % South
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=below:\Large{$\mathcal{S}$}] (S) at (0,-3.5) {};

        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (s) at (0,-3.5) {};
    % West
    \node[thick,draw=black,circle,
        minimum size=0.3cm,
        label=left:\Large{$\mathcal{W}$}] (W) at (-3.5,0) {};

        \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,
        minimum size=1.5mm] (w) at (-3.5,0) {};
    \end{scope}

    % mainlines
    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (N);

    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (E);

    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (S);

    \draw[thick,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.1pt}]
        (centre) -- (W);

    % Main points
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=blue] (-0.35cm,0.35cm) -- (N.north) -- (centre.center) -- cycle; % why u no fill?!!


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aah, so \filldraw needs "this exact point" rather than "this general area" as parametres?

Comment: The problem is more that you have a path with holes. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315470/why-does-cycle-not-return-to-the-starting-node-at-all-if-i-construct-a-p